# How to use a django project packed using pip?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pip, pypi

I just finished writing a django project, packed it using:

```
$ python setup.py sdist 
$ python setup.py register
$ python setup.py sdist upload
```

and it's now ready and waiting in the pypi.

I created a brand new virtualenv environment, activated it and then hit

```
$ pip install qkreator
```

'qkreator' is the name of my package :)

**How am I supposed to run it?**

It's now installed inside the virtualenv in `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quiz_creator/` but it doesn't have a manage.py file inside - even  though I included it in the MANIFEST.in when i packed everything

(When developing the project i used to run it using `$ python manage.py runserver`)

P.S. There are also some full paths in my settings.py file. How am I supposed to make those dynamic ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the paths in your settings.py dynamic you could use the following approach:

```
import os.path
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) #set PROJECT_ROOT to the path where your settings.py is available
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static/') #join PROJECT_ROOT with the relative folder where static files are to be found
```